# Tutorial for User Autentication using Dart

Tags: session, authentication, cookies, dart

I'm traying to develop a web app using Dart for both sever and client.

Anyone know if exist any tutorial for implement User Authentication using the features included in Dart library ( Http Server, Session, Cookie )?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use the [rikulo security addon](http://docs.rikulo.org/stream/latest/Add-ons/Rikulo_Security/).
You can find [here](https://github.com/rikulo/security/tree/master/example/hello) is a good example.

Comment: The question was written when there was no rikulo security addon. Why did you downgrade the question?

Comment: I didn't downgrade the question. Just answer it.